# Unity Google Analytics causing issue in game scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

In my **Android** game i have 2 game scenes and I want to add analytics to both of them.

but unfortunately, when i enable the google analytics plugins in my second scene, some textures are not getting set -- issue.

I have tried 2 plugin(s) and both have caused same issue.
http://g3zarstudios.com/blog/google-analytics-in-unity/
http://massthreat.com/labs/googleanalytics

To use them, I'm attaching the script to either the main camera of the scene or a game object where events are handled.

But the analytics is only called upon client trigger.

Answer (score 0):

http://massthreat.com/labs/googleanalytics . this one works but after a minor change.

Convert the function (LogScreen) to a co-routine. WWW class takes time to get response on different devices. If you use it in a function, then it will expect a response in the next frame.

If its a coroutine, you can yield control after you get a response.